# Problems with javascript on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well I have a site where I am trying to make a form comming up with a alert box but without submiting..

I have done this with Javascript at Codepen.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBhaL

But when I put this on my website it doesn't work for some reasons.

Does anyone know what the problem can be..

Site: http://www.marktopper.dk/demo/blog_post.php?id=22
Please scroll down and try the comment submition.

I have put the javascript into a file called "ajax.js", and I can see that the site gets it.
But it doesn't seems to work like on Codepen.

I have also changed from using local jquery to using the latest jquery from their site.
But still without luck.

Comment: Here is the whole source for `blog_post.php`: http://pastebin.com/XK982qEc              Source of `ajax.js`: http://www.marktopper.dk/demo/ajax.js

Comment: PLease include your code in your question directly as well as provide a link to a working example. Some people are behind restrictive proxies, sometimes sites are down or disappear forever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ajax.js` is currently:-

```
$("#commentForm").submit(function(){
 alert("i've submitted this form");
 return false;
});
```

This runs before the DOM is ready. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#commentForm").submit(function(){
   alert("i've submitted this form");
   return false;
  });
});
```

[Introducing $(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the error.